# Switching to frames fails sometime (4 out of 5) times. Without changing any code

Tags: selenium, frames

```
Set<String> windows2 = w.getWindowHandles();
            System.out.println(windows2.size());
            for(String handles : windows2)
            {
                w.switchTo().window(handles);
            }
            System.out.println("Windows after itteration : "+windows2.size());
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            System.out.println(w.getTitle());
            w.switchTo().frame(w.findElement(By.xpath("//frame[@name='MainFrame1']")));
            w.findElement(By.name("blnggrp")).click();
            w.switchTo().defaultContent();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            Set<String> windows3 = w.getWindowHandles();
            System.out.println(windows3.size());
            for(String hanldes : windows3)
            {
                w.switchTo().window(hanldes);
            }
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            w.switchTo().frame(w.findElement(By.xpath("//frame[@name='code_desc']")));
            w.findElement(By.name("resulted_cond")).click();
            w.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

> Error : Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element
>   with xpath == //frame[@name='code_desc']

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Thread.sleep()`, try using waits. There are 2 types - implicit wait and explicit wait. You can learn more about it from [here](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits).

For now try removing all `Thread.sleep()` statements and set an implicit wait for the driver and then execute your code:

```
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
```

Comment: Even if I use Implicitly wait also its throwing this error, when i compile the script for 5 times without any changes in the code, its being executed only one or 2 times, I dunno why the other trials fails.

Comment: Ur code doesn't work. TimeSpan class in not available in selenium.

Comment: @CheenuA - I'm not very familiar with C#. But I got that code from the docs. Here is the [link](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#implicit-waits). Check your imports.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I would use is the WebDriver's driver.switchTo().frame() method but avoiding the index number (you are using a combination of window handles and the ID)  The  `w.switchTo().window(handles);` is the cause of your errant failures. You can remove that and select the window you want using;

- A number. (0 based index normally but NOT always with IE)
- A name or
  ID.
- A previously found WebElement.

An example:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.name("blnggrp")));
```

As suggested by Jason if you combine this with implicit waits you will have the best solution

```
driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
```

Comment: In the above code you have mentioned, it doesn't workout for me in any case. Its throwing an error like "unable to find element == name("blnggrp")". First of all we should mention the frame name, bcos my element blnggrp is inside frame name "MainFrame1". so 1st we should give the control to window and frame and then element. Rite ?

Comment: my example assumes blnggrp is a unique name element on the frame/window you want to switch to.  If you can, use an ID as your identifier.  I suggested blnggrp as it was in your example code.